# Unable to locate packages in docker container

Tags: git, docker, ubuntu-14.04, dockerfile

While trying to build my repository inside a docker container, I need to install git:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install -y git
```

to build the container i run the following command:

```
sudo docker build .
```

I get the following error on every package i try to install:

```
 E: Unable to locate package git
 The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y git' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

All the answers i found were claiming that i need to run apt-get update first, which i do.

EDIT:

Tried to run all of the commands in one line:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
```

which yielded the following error:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package git
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y git' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Comment: try with all your commands in one RUN, like `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git`

Comment: Please include your entire Dockerfile used to reproduce your error, and indicate if you have any proxy servers or other network filters of any kind.

Comment: This is sufficient  to reproduce the error. No special network filter. Just my personal computer. @BMitch

Comment: which OS for your host? Linux, Max, Win?

Comment: It's insufficient to reproduce, you don't include a FROM line to know your source container. Include a complete example please.

Comment: @BMitch you are correct, sorry for that. Edited. I'm running on ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: on your host, does `sudo apt-get update` work fine?

Comment: Yes, no special problem with my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your updated output, you show your `apt-get update` is failing, DNS resolution failed. This is a network connectivity issue you need to resolve first before you'll be able to build images that pull packages from the network.

Comment: I changed WiFi and now it works. Do you know what the problem might have been?

Comment: Docker does a lot with the networking stack under the covers to give each container an isolated network. There are bridges created and lots of iptables rules. Without doing a lot of hands on debugging in your environment, I would only be guessing at your specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to aggregate the RUN, btw try this:

```
RUN set -ue \
    ; apt-get -y update \
    ; apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests git \
    ; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
;
```

and when you run the build:

`docker build -t <name-of-your-image> .`